# Matrix whose spectral moments (traces of its powers) follow a geometric progression

Tags: matrices, characteristic-polynomial

I am looking for a square $n \times n$ matrix $A$ such that its spectral moments follow a geometric progression: $Tr(A^r) = k^r$, for some $k$. I believe this to be impossible since $Tr(A^0) = Tr(I) = n$. So perhaps I should be looking for something like
$$
Tr(A^r) = n^{r+1},
$$
or something like
$$
Tr(A^r) = nk^{r}.
$$

I'm interested in complex or real matrices, though other fields would be acceptable. Apologies if the question sounds vague, but I am dealing with an open ended question here!

**What I have tried:** I know that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial can be expressed in terms of the spectral moments using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_characteristic_polynomial_of_a_matrix). In this way, I can fix the traces of $A,\ldots,A^n$ to be whatever I want, find the corresponding polynomial, and find a matrix whose characteristic polynomial matches it. However, this does not give me any control on the spectral moments of powers greater than $n$. So I'm beginning to wonder if this is at all possible.

Also note that for $n=1$ this is trivial since $A$ is just an element of the underlying field and we have $Tr(A^r) = A^r$. I'm interested in $n>1$.

**EDIT:** if possible, I would also like $A$ to be invertible...

Comment: The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Comment: What's wrong with diagonal matrices with $A = \mathrm{diag}(k,\dots,k)$? Then we have $tr(A^r) = tr(\mathrm{diag}(k^r,\dots,k^r)) = n k^r$. In general, I believe you could choose any matrix for which all the Eigenvalues are equal to $k$, since the trace is the sum of the Eigenvalues and the Eigenvalues of the power of a matrix are the powers of the Eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim** Over characteristic-0 field $\mathbb{F}$ (such as $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$), if $A$ satisfies the condition, then $A$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$ in $\bar{\mathbb{F}}$.

*Proof*: Suppose $\operatorname{Tr}A^k=nr^k$.

If $r\neq 0$, we find $\operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A)^k=n$ for all $k$.  We calculate the coefficient $c_k$ in the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{r^{-1}A}(t)=\det(tI-r^{-1}A)=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k t^k$ by
\begin{align*}
c_{n-k}&=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\begin{vmatrix}
\operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A) & k-1\\
\operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A)^2 & \operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A) & k-2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A)^{k-1} & \operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A)^{k-2} &\dots & \dots & 1\\
\operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A)^k & \operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A)^{k-1} &\dots & \dots & \operatorname{Tr}(r^{-1}A)\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\begin{vmatrix}
n & k-1\\
n & n & k-2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
n & n &\dots & \dots & 1\\
n & n &\dots & \dots & n\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\begin{vmatrix}
(n-k+1) & k-1\\
0 & n & k-2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
0 & n &\dots & \dots & 1\\
0 & n &\dots & \dots & n\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\frac{(n-k+1)}{k}(-1)c_{n-k+1}
\end{align*}
So starting from $c_n:=1$, we have $c_{n-1}=-n, c_{n-2}=\binom{n}2, c_{n-3}=-\binom{n}3, \dots$ and so the characteristic polynomial of $r^{-1}A$ is $\chi_{r^{-1}A}(t)=(t-1)^n$.  Hence $\chi_A(t)=(t-r)^n$.

If $r=0$, then all elementary polynomials in the eigenvalues are $0$ from Newton's identity, so $\chi_A(t)=t^n$.  QED.

So the only possibilities of $A$, when working in characteristic 0, are of the form
$$
A=rI+N
$$
where $N$ is nilpotent.

Over positive characteristic you have other possibilities.  For example, over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $n=2p$, $p>2$, any matrix of the form
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
aI+U & C\\
0 & bI+V
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for any $a,b\in\mathbb{F}$, any strictly upper-triangular $U,V$ and any $C$ will have $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)=0$ for $k>0$.

Comment: Excellent! If I'm not mistaken, your argument can be easily extended to show that if $Tr(A^k) = (n-s)r^k$ then its characteristic polynomial must be $t^s (t-r)^{n-s}$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the recursion formula becomes $c_{n-k}=-\frac{n-s-k+1}{k}c_{n-k+1}$ giving $c_{n-1}=-(n-s)$, $c_{n-2}=\binom{n-s}{2}$, etc. $c_{s-1}=0=c_{s-2}=\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal elements $D_{ii} = k$. Then,
$$ \mathrm{tr}(D^r) = \mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{diag}(k,\dots,k)^r) = \mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{diag}(k^r,\dots,k^r)) = nk^r. $$

Comment: Since $D=kI$ commutes with every other $n\times n$ matrix, $A=UDU^{-1}=D$.

Comment: True, so maybe $\mathrm{diag}(k,\dots,k)$ is the only possible choice after all. I removed the superfluous generalization from the answer.